# Upsample pandas data right index inclusive

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data which I want to resample (upsample) into sometimes 30 minute intervals, sometimes 15 minute intervals, sometime 5 minute intervals

```py
                 TIME              VALUE
0 2023-01-02 01:00:00              94.73
1 2023-01-02 02:00:00              95.30
2 2023-01-02 03:00:00              67.16
```

However, if I use pandas `.resample()` method, upsampling on the last index is not performed. Is there some way to achieve this?

What I have tried:

```py
>>> df.set_index('TIME').resample('30T').ffill()
                   TIME              VALUE
0  2023-01-02 01:00:00              94.73
1  2023-01-02 01:30:00              94.73
2  2023-01-02 02:00:00              95.30
3  2023-01-02 02:30:00              95.30
4  2023-01-02 03:00:00              67.16
```

What I want:

```py
                   TIME              VALUE
0  2023-01-02 01:00:00              94.73
1  2023-01-02 01:30:00              94.73
2  2023-01-02 02:00:00              95.30
3  2023-01-02 02:30:00              95.30
4  2023-01-02 03:00:00              67.16
5  2023-01-02 03:30:00              67.16
```

Comment: This is no longer an interpolation but rather an extrapolation, manually add the timepoint, then resample

Comment: @mozway this happens within a groupby, so i would have to loop over the groups, infer what the last timepoint should be, add it, and then resample, and finally perform a `pd.concat` to achieve what is essentially a one-liner save the last index which I am missing. `df.set_index('TME').groupby(['COL1', 'COL2', 'COL3']).resample('30T').ffill()` - is there no better way?

Comment: Shouldn't using the argument `closed='right'` when you call the `resample()` method make the resampling inclusive of the right edge of the time intervals?

Comment: @Kylar tried it, but it doesnt work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'TIME': ['2023-01-02 01:00:00', '2023-01-02 02:00:00', '2023-01-02 03:00:00'],
        'VALUE': [94.73, 95.30, 67.16]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.set_index('TIME', inplace=True)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

df = df.resample('30T', closed='right', label='right').ffill()

last_index = df.index[-1]
if last_index + pd.Timedelta('30 min') not in df.index:
    last_row = pd.DataFrame({'VALUE': df.iloc[-1, 0]}, index=[last_index + pd.Timedelta('30 min')])
    df = pd.concat([df, last_row])

df = df.reset_index()

print(df)
```

which gives:

```
                index  VALUE
0 2023-01-02 01:00:00  94.73
1 2023-01-02 01:30:00  94.73
2 2023-01-02 02:00:00  95.30
3 2023-01-02 02:30:00  95.30
4 2023-01-02 03:00:00  67.16
5 2023-01-02 03:30:00  67.16
```

Comment: not the answer i was hoping for, but it works, so thanks for the help :)